# On what condition will make "$S^{\perp} \subseteq T^{\perp} \Longrightarrow T \subseteq S$" true?

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

Suppose that $V$ is a $\mathbb{F}$-vector space with some $\mathbb{F}$ a field, and denote $V^{'} := \{l: V \to \mathbb{F} \,\, \mid $ $l$ is linear$\}$, the dual space of $V$. Define the annihilator of a subset $S \subseteq V$ by

$$ S^{\perp} := \{l \in V^{'} \, \, \mid l(s)=0, \forall s \in S\} $$

It is true that if $S, T \subseteq V$ are subsets such that $S \subseteq T$, then $T^{\perp} \subseteq S^{\perp}$.

Now, assume $S^{\perp} \subseteq T^{\perp}$. On what conditions will make $T \subseteq S$ be true? If impossible, why?

Thanks.

### EDIT

Is it when $S$ and $T$ are subspaces of each other? That is, is it when $S$ is a subspace of $T$ (assuming already that $S$ and $T$ are subspaces of $V$)?

### EDIT 2

To make it clear, I want to know the conditions so that

> If $S^{\perp} \subseteq T^{\perp}$, then $T \subseteq S$

is true.

Comment: @BrianMoehring exactly, I searched on the definition of a dual space and I found that it's just the set of linear functions $l: V \to \mathbb{F}$. I didn't see anything else.

Comment: @BrianMoehring No. Can you make an answer, please?

Comment: Your first statement,
$$\text{If } S,T\subseteq V \text{are subsets such that } S\subseteq T, \text{then } T^{\perp} \subseteq S^{\perp}.$$ holds trivially for every such $S,T$. In fact it is usually one of the standard properties listed in any intermediate/advanced Linear Algebra text.

Comment: @sadman-ncc, I know that property, but I want to know IF $S^{\perp} \subseteq T^{\perp} \Longrightarrow T \subseteq S$, and on what conditions it's true.

Comment: In finite-dimensional, purely algebraic settings, this will work for pretty standard reasons. In infinite dimensions, like in an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, the "complements" are necessarily closed... but it could be that $T\not\subset S$ because $S$ is not closed, so does not include some (otherwise harmless) limit points of $T$. Topological closedness should suffice for what you want. It's certainly necessary. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett, does it mean that the $\mathbb{F}$-vector space $V$ need to be at least a normed space with topological closedness to work (here, I mean that a norm induces a metric to define closedness)?

Comment: @JoshuaOrtiz, a norm would be sufficient, and an assumption (at least for simplicity) that the big ambient space is _complete_, and that the subspaces are _closed_. Then things work as expected. Otherwise, there are fairly boring, but dangerous, traps.

Comment: Thanks! This will help a lot!

Comment: There are other fancier (but/and useful!) types of topological vector spaces than complete normed spaces, with fancier (but/and useful) notions of completeness... But it's good to look at the complete normed-space example (=Banach spaces) at the beginning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137660/discussion-between-joshua-ortiz-and-paul-garrett).